# Invalid argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying show print page by on click method, but IE9 shows me error "invalid argument" in printWindow variable. Where is the problem?

```
print.on('click', function(){
  var printWindow = window.open(print.data('url'), print.data('title'), "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,width=820");
  printWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: You tell us. What's in `print.data('url')`? What's in `print.data('title')`? What happens when you just type that `window.open(...)` statment, with those strings used directly, in the console?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe one of your arguments is invalid. You could try a process called "debugging", where you replace them one by one until you find the problem.